# Structured Streaming aggregating without grouping

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions, spark-structured-streaming

For a project we need to analyse streamed prices (market data) on possible anomalies. We require the "Average" and the "Standard Deviation" of those incoming prices over a specific time period.

Our approach is with the "Structured Streaming" api. The problem is: We have to aggregate over each window for the AVG/STTDEV but afterwards we need to analyse each price on it's own. So grouping is "out of the window". The rest of the algorithm would be simple enough to use an UDF.

What we already tried:

- Reading the stream twice, doing aggregations on the first table and join it with the other:
  Didn't work because apparently you can't aggregate before joining.
- Use memory output and do the computations further below:
  Did work but we soon had a memory problem.
- We also tried using the "Arbitrary Stateful" approach but we don't know if that is the "correct solution" for this problem nor were we able to implement it correctly yet.

Our code for the second option looks like this (mostly taken from the programming guide):

```
val lines = spark.readStream
 .format("socket")
 .option("host", "localhost")
 .option("port", 9998)
 .load()

val words = lines.select(split($"value", ",")(0).cast("int").as("Seq_Nr"),
                    split($"value", ",")(1).cast("int").as("VN"),
                    split($"value", ",")(5).as("VAS"),
                    split($"value", ",")(6).cast("float").as("Price"),
                    split($"value", ",")(11).cast("timestamp").as("timestamp"))

val wordCounts = words.select(window($"timestamp", "5 seconds", "5 seconds"), $"Seq_Nr", $"VN", $"VAS", $"Price", $"timestamp")

val streamingETLQuery = wordCounts
 .writeStream
 .queryName("counts")
 .format("memory")
 .outputMode("complete")
 .start()

val df = spark.sql("select * from counts")

"Do aggregations and anomaly detection algorithm on DF"
```

The goal would be: Create a window over the "timestamp", aggregate for AVG/STDDEV, analyse each price afterwards.

So the questions would be: Is there any possible way to do an aggregation without grouping the data? If not is there possibly any other approach without using memory output?

We're also starting to question if "Structured Streaming" is the right solution for our use case.

Many thanks in advance!